# Vagrant Docker provisioner on 32 bit machines

Tags: docker, vagrant

I have a requirement to build a 32 bit VM containing several linked docker containers.

I have a script that successfully uses the `vagrant` `docker` provisioner and `vagrant-docker-compose` to build the containers and link them together in a 64 bit trusty machine (`ubuntu/trusty64`) but when I try it on a 32 bit machine it fails  - `vagrant` spots that `docker` needs installing, but fails with:

`E: Unable to locate package lxc-docker`

I tried to find a 32 bit base box with `docker` built in that would work OTS with the `vagrant` `docker` provisioner (my preferred solution) but can't seem to find one?

I guess the next step would be to try to build an install `docker` myself from within the `vagrant` script before I call on the `docker` provisioner? If so, what would such a script look like?

Comment: A 64-bit container isn't going to run in a 32-bit VM. Unless I misunderstand, this is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: I want to run a VM containing a 32 bit ubuntu o/s containing containers running 32 bit apps.

Comment: Well, it is possible, but 1) you will need to build or obtain a 32-bit version of docker and 2) build or obtain 32-bit containers (the ones on the Hub are almost entirely 64-bit). Unless you know what you're doing, this isn't going to be easy - all the effort has gone into 64-bit Docker so far.

Comment: Yep - I know... looks like I'm going to have to dump a containerised version of a VM and just go back to a monolithic VM build:-(